# How to save and load array of information effectively? (Datagridview) vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, datagridview, save, load

Hello expert coders,

I have a problem with my coding in vb.net where I do not know how to save arrays of information effectively. This information is going to contain job #, customer names as well some detailed information.

I've been using Access Database to store linear information using 1 table, but now I have to store vector arrays for "each" job.

For example, for job# 1000, customer is "Jimmy" and date entered is "Today"
for that job, I can have

Index:  Glass type:  Thickness:  Cost:
1         Clear         3/8"      $100
2         Obscure       1/2"      $120
3         Optiwhite     3/8"      $200
~
n

and the user can add as many glass types by clicking (Add Glass Lite)

I know I can make new tables for each job on Access Database, but if I am going to have about 200 new jobs everyday, I'm not sure it's the best way to have like 2000 tables in Access.

I tried saving Datagridview table as name.dat file, and read it.. but this gave me a problem where if some cells are blank, I can't read it property because it can't determine what the delimiter is... here is my code below

```
  Private Sub butSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butSave.Click
    SaveGridData(RadGridView1, ThisFilename)
End Sub

Private Sub butLoad_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles butLoad.Click
    LoadGridData(RadGridView1, ThisFilename)
End Sub

Private Sub SaveGridData(ByRef ThisGrid As RadGridView, ByVal Filename As String)
    RadGridView1.ClipboardCopyMode = GridViewClipboardCopyMode.EnableWithoutHeaderText

    RadGridView1.SelectAll()
    IO.File.WriteAllText(Filename, RadGridView1.GetClipboardContent().GetText.TrimEnd)
    RadGridView1.ClearSelection()

End Sub

Private Sub LoadGridData(ByRef ThisGrid As RadGridView, ByVal Filename As String)
    Quality_EnclosuresDataSet.tGlassEntry.Clear()


    For Each ThisLine In My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText(Filename).Split(Environment.NewLine)
        Quality_EnclosuresDataSet.tGlassEntry.Rows.Add(Split(ThisLine, "    "))
    Next
End Sub
```

I am very new to Access and VB.net (and saving job data.) I have basic knowledge in coding and logic, that's why I need some right direction in which I need to study.

so, just to wrap up, my question is:

1. what is the best way to store job data (that contains vector data) and load
2. saving it to .txt file or .dat file is the best way, how can I do this more effectively? it seems unstable
3. Any recommended topic I need to study? in regards to job database saving/loading

Comment: If you store the data in a datatable you can bind it to the DGV and Save and Write the table to XML using built in methods.  See [DataTable Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataTable(v=vs.110).aspx).  **But** if there is an access DB why save to text or XML instead of the DB?

Comment: thanks, thats one direction I didn't know that I can learn.

Comment: can I make a folder in Access where I can hide all the job-related tables?(Sorry, I just figured out how to group tables, so I guess I will be figuring out how to save small tables for each job now)

Comment: You should read up on what a DB is and Database programming in general.  There is no reason to create many identical small tables.  In fact it is what you are *not* supposed to do,